# XDocument Exception: Root element is missing

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Config>
<NumOfBytesInRow>20</NumOfBytesInRow>
<FirstBaudRate>115200</FirstBaudRate>
<SecondBaudRate>34800</SecondBaudRate>
<DefaultPort>COM1</DefaultPort>
<NumOfTries>2</NumOfTries>
</Config>
```

And I'm trying to get the elements, but as soon as I'm opening the file I'm getting an exception that the root element is missing

```
XDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
```

**EDIT**

I have added:

```
if(File.Exists("D:\\BBConfig.xml"))
```

before the load it found the file and still same error

Comment: Check with if (File.Exists(path)) whether the file is found.

Comment: I added the "if" it found it but still same error

Comment: You can read the file in a string and use LoadXml(string) -just for sure ...

Comment: @duDE How can i read it as string?

Comment: Have added as answer because too much for comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first I find the answer of user3890766 very good: "This exception could be thrown if the method can't find the file". But nevertheless you can try this for sure:

```
    string strXml;
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myXML.xml"))
        {
             strXml = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(strXml);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception could be thrown if the method can't find the file. You need to check if your application can find the file at the given path, and have the authorization to read it.

To be sure, you could use a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx), and check the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length(v=vs.110).aspx). Then use `XmlDocument.Load` with this `Stream`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if it is not autorized to read it, how can i change it?

Comment: @bahbah You're most likely on Windows, you need to go on the properties of the file and check in the security tab if the user has read or read and write access.